# Plotting city locations on Python 3

Tags: python, mapping, plot, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

My question is a follow-up of this:
[plotting US cities on a map with matplotlib and basemap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198530/plotting-us-cities-on-a-map-with-matplotlib-and-basemap).
I would like to use some Python library to plot on a map city locations, starting from a list like this:

```
    L = ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille', '...']
```

In the linked GIS question, this was easily achieved through Basemap, which has however been deprecated in favour of Cartopy and does not currently work on Pyhton 3. Is there a simple way to achieve the same result with Cartopy or another library?

This [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5xvofn/how_to_plot_city_locations_in_cartopy/deldavv/) may be helpful for advanced users but being a newbie I was looking for something more intuitive.

Comment: For questions about code please always provide a code attempt.

Comment: @PolyGeo sorry for not making the question clear enough. As for the code, I was asking how to reproduce the one in the linked GIS question with a different library (Cartopy instead of the deprecated Basemap). I'm editing the question to further clarify desidered behaviour and problem statement.

Comment: You could review questions here tagged [tag:cartopy] to see whether any help you to do something geospatial with your Python list.

Comment: You could geocode the places using geopy and then look at whether returned lat/long values could be plotted using cartopy.

Comment: @PolyGeo this should work fine, I'll check it out to see if I can implement it. Thank you.